# How to compute triple integral in spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I need to compute: $\displaystyle\int \int \int  z  dxdydz$

over the domain: $\left\{x^2+y^2+z^2\leqslant 16,z\geqslant 0\right\}$

Im trying to use spherical coords as:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{4} r \cos(\theta )r^2\sin(\varphi ) \;dr\,d\theta \,d\varphi
\end{equation}

It gives me $0$ as result. But i know that is wrong, the same formula computed with Mathematica software returns $64 \pi$.

```
{x, y, z} = 
  r {Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]};

Integrate[
 z Abs[Det[D[{x, y, z}, {{r, θ, ϕ}}]]], 
   {r, 0, 4}, {θ, 0, π/2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

My procedure is:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{4} r \cos(\theta )r^2\sin(\varphi ) \;dr\,d\theta \,d\varphi=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{4} r^3 \cos(\theta )\sin(\varphi ) \;dr\,d\theta \,d\varphi=$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}64 \cos(\theta ) \sin(\varphi ) d\theta d\varphi = \int_{0}^{2\pi} -64 \sin(\varphi ) d\varphi = 64 \cos(2\pi  ) - 64 \cos(0)=0$$

**EDIT:**
I see the name of the angles can be confusing, so this is mi current notation:

$x=r \sin(\theta ) \cos (\varphi )$

$y=r \sin(\theta ) \sin (\varphi )$

$z=r \cos(\theta)$

$\varphi$ should be the azimuthal angle, and $\theta$ the polar angle

Comment: This will be zero because sine is integrated over its period. Could you please designate the task more precisely?

Comment: Even WolframAlpha agrees with the result of 0, are you sure that's supposed to be $\sin{\varphi}$ and not $\sin{\theta}$?

Comment: The Jacobian for spherical coordinates is $r^2\sin\varphi$, so that is probably correct.

Comment: You appear to be using $ \ \theta \ $ as the "polar angle" and $ \ \phi \ $ as the "azimuthal angle".  So the factor $ \ \sin  \ \phi \ $ ought to be $ \ \sin \  \theta \ $ . (After your edit: Yes, if you have $ \ z \ $ as $ \ r \ \cos \ \theta \ $ , then that factor with sine _is_ incorrect and you _will_ get a non-zero result if you are integrating over a hemisphere. [Were you to integrate over the full sphere, the integral would be zero again...] )

Comment: @ТимофейЛомоносов Pleas, see my edit.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Could you explain me why this is wrong?, I dont get it.

Comment: Between $\theta$ and $\varphi$, which angle is your azimuthal angle and which is your polar angle? That will let us know how you need to fix your integral.

Comment: You must watch out when writing the infinitesimal factors for volume in spherical coordinates; unfortunately, there are multiple conventions.  You are using the one where $ \ \theta \ $ is the polar angle with $ \ \theta \ = \ 0 \ $ at the "north pole" and $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ at the "equator".  The azimuthal angle, which runs the full circle of $ \ 2 \pi \ $ around the $ \ z-$ axis, is denoted as $ \ \phi \ $ in that convention.  This makes $ \ z \ = \ r \ \cos \ \theta \ $ and the "horizontal" circles have radii of $ \ r \ \sin \ \theta \ $ .

Comment: @Wyvern666, you mixed the physics and mathematics conventions for naming variables in spherical coordinates. $\sin{\varphi}$ should be $\sin{\theta}$ if you're keeping those integration limits.

Comment: To see how fully awful the practice is for spherical coordinates, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html ("Most" mathematicians use the convention on the first or second line of the table, "most" physicists use the last.)  Your set-up is based on this: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/math/immath/sphcoordel.gif

Comment: If there's $\sin(\theta)$ it's of no use. $\cos\theta\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)$ and we will again get the zero value.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I think im using the first of the table

Comment: @ТимофейЛомоносов   **Wyvern666** is only integrating over the "upper" hemisphere; the full sphere _would_ give zero.

Comment: @Wyvern666  Then see the diagram in the second link in my earlier comment.

Comment: Gah!  I read the Wolfram table backward: you are using the "Arfken" line; the diagram is the one I linked to, though. (Moving among these conventions is crazy-making sometimes...)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Please, see mi new edit.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I made a mistake again, $\theta$ is the polar angle. Edited

Comment: Then my earlier comments still stand: the sine factor is incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean the jacobian?

Comment: Yes.  The integral is "separable" as $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}  d\varphi \ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(\theta )\sin(\theta)  \ d\theta  \ \int_{0}^{4} r^3  \ dr\ \ \ . $$  You will now obtain $ \ 64 \pi \ $ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner So mi problem is just that i incorrectly computed the jacobian for mi x,y,z definition?

Comment: It would seem so -- this happens to people _a lot_ because of the differing notations for the spherical angles.  So beware...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in (1) where $\sin\varphi$ should be $\sin\theta$.

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin\theta d\varphi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta \int_{0}^{4}r^2dr (r \cos\theta ) $$

$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\varphi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin\theta \cos\theta d\theta \int_{0}^{4}r^3dr =2\pi*(1/2)* 64=64\pi$$